# Spring profiles activate all datasource

Tags: java, spring

I was trying to use spring profiles to create separate datasources for dev/prod servers.

```
    <beans profile="hsqldb">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/schema-hsqldb.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>

<beans profile="oracle">
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.1:1521/XXX"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Problem is that I can't activate profile correctly. I tried both web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>hsqldb</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and `-Dspring.profiles.active=hsqldb`.

In both cases HSQLDB is working but I also have Oracle exceptions in log (like 2nd datasource is active too):

```
    2014-08-13 10:39:57.216 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Wyjątek we-wy: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
```

How I can force spring to use only one profile and ignore another?

Comment: try -Dspring.profiles.active="hsqldb" (with quotation marks)